# Do Unity webapps work in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, webapps

I'm using the latest stable Chrome for Linux built from Google and I just installed the Unity WebApps preview.

Unfortunately I can't figure out how to set it up. In tutorials I read that unity should ask me by itself to integrate a web app as soon as I use it. This does not seem to happen.

I only saw it working with Firefox in video, though. Is Google Chrome supported?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Unity Webapps work in Firefox and Chromium, and they could be made to work in other browsers as well. There's a library that encapsulates most of the code to write an extension.
Chromium that you can download from everywhere will find the extension and load it. So you'll get basic webapp integration. There's a patch, that adds the ability to manipulate the list of integrated sites, but everything else will work without that patch.

Chrome will not find the extension. 
The patch for laoding extensions off the filesystem was merged upstream in Chromium an is in the latest release of Chrome, but it looks in a different path than where the extension is installed.
If you would install the extension where Chrome would look at it should work. But webapps are not tested with Chrome.

The answer was given in following "Ubuntu on Air" hangout: https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=6K_n8DtDl2k#t=42m42s

The above is basically a transscript of the Answers by Robert Carr and Ken VanDine (Ubuntu Webapps Team)

You should have know where the answer was to be found: at Time: 42m42s ;-)

Comment: Hello Philipp, could you please change your answer to make it contain the actual answer? You could do it like this, for example: "Yes, to get it working you should do X, and then Y. Afterwards, do Z. Source: <URL you gave>"

Comment: is there a way to make chrome look in the right path? A tutorial on how to make it work perhaps.

Answer (score 8):

By the momment Unity Webapps it is only avialable for [Firefox](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/firefox) [image: Install Software] and [Chromium](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/chromium-browser) [image: Install Software]. As Google Chrome is based on Chromium, it shouldn't be hard to export Webapps to it.

Remeber this is preview software you should fully expect to encounter bugs.

Answer (score 3):

Google Chrome is not supported at the moment.

The issue with Google Chrome is that there are a few pieces missing that prevent us from having the complete "WebApps" experience:

- support for "infobars" extension cap is still missing and set as experimental (putting it out of experimental being postponed again and again due to some issues in MacOS),
- support for some form of tld resolution (chrome.tld was proposed as an extension upstream w/o success, maybe I should go back at it),
- no "chromeless" (although we could somehow come close with "app mode"),

We could have a limited (but acceptable) WebApps experience support for Chrome though,

---

To test out what does function, you must install chromium-browser and unity-chromium-extension then copy some files.

Copy `pmoflmbbcfgacopiikdcpmbiellfihdg` from `~/.config/chromium/Default/Extensions/` to `~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Extensions/` and it should show up next time you launch Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Now you can use web apps with Google chrome browsers. 
It is very simple to activate them.
Use following instructions ...http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/12/how-to-enable-web-apps-in-google-chrome-on-ubuntu